# Advantages of checking in on a thrown-away return leg flight?

Tags: bookings, check-in

As we know, when you need to fly one-way, very often it is cheaper to book a round-trip/open jaw, and throw away the return ticket.

Are there any practical advantages to check in online into this thrown-away return flight? Of course you are not taking it anyway, so I'm asking about other advantages?

One possible advantage is that you might get miles for the trip; my experience on this, however, been mixed.

I've also been reading [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26677/what-is-the-purpose-of-check-in-before-flying?rq=1), and it appears there's another possible reason. The way I read the answer, if your flight was booked through Expedia or agent, and you do not check in for return, Expedia keeps the money. If you check in, then the airline gets the money (even if you don't fly). And I still like airlines more than Expedia (and this might explan why sometime you get miles).

So, are there any other practical advantages (or disadvantages) to check in online into the thrown-away return flight?

Comment: If the flight is cancelled, you might be eligible for compensation or rebooking at a time when you might actually want to use the return half of the flight

Comment: You are reading that answer wrong: the airline gets paid for the entire trip when you first check in.

Comment: Isn't this kind of ticket booking generally against airline's terms? (even without checking in)

Comment: @chx The airline gets paid when you buy the ticket. Check-in has absolutely nothing to do with it

Comment: @Doc that's not what the linked answer says: "At check in, the airline receives the relevant flight coupon(s) from the ticket or electronic ticket. The coupon, whether paper or electronic, is needed for the operating airline to claim the value of the flight back from the original travel agent or airline that issued the ticket, and who received the money from the purchaser in the first place."

Comment: @chx Turns out, answers on StackExchange aren't always right...

Comment: Then that answer needs fixing.

Comment: @chx: even if the return trip is on a different airline? If the first leg is on KLM, and return is on Delta, are both KLM and Delta paid when I check into KLM flight?

Comment: "As we know, when you need to fly one-way, very often it is cheaper to book a round-trip/open jaw," That used to be true but in my experience, that's not the case anymore. You can typically get a one way for 50%-75% of the round trip price

Comment: @Hilmar: this is still the case on most routes I fly. What you say seems to be only true at routes where mainstream carriers have to compete with low-cost carriers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "best for (almost) everybody" approach to this is to NOT check-in for the flight you don't intend to take.  This allows the airline to know that you do not intend to fly, and allows them to re-allocate your seat (if needed) sooner - for example, by clearing someone on the standby list.  It also means that they won't waste any time waiting for you to turn up at the gate, paging you, etc.  If you have checked in they will still be able to re-allocate your seat, but they will normally have to wait until closer to the departure time to do so, when things are already generally fairly hectic!

However there is one potential situation where checking-in might work to your advantage.  If the flight you were due to be on is excessively delayed, or if it is canceled, and that delay/cancellation occurs very close to the flight time, then you may stand a better chance of obtaining compensation and/or your money back for the flight if you are checked in.

In some cases even if there is a delay/cancellation you will not be able to do anything simply because you are not at the airport, however many airlines now will allow you to arrange for compensation/refunds over the phone, and sometimes even at a later time.  Depending on the exact situation you may be able to do this even if you have not checked in, but depending on the exact situation being checked in will give you slightly more leverage.

There is a second situation where check-in can be beneficial, but it is very much a corner case.  If you are going to be at the airport anyway (eg, you are connecting, and the throw-away flight is the connection), AND if the flight you are not planning to fly is oversold, then you may be able to volunteer to be "denied boarding" - ie, give up your seat on that flight and be moved to a later flight, and in doing so receive some form of compensation.  The catch with this is that you will need to wait at the gate right up until departure time before they will know that they need your seat so you will need to invest some time, plus if it turns out that they do not need your seat it's going to be rather odd for you to turn around and say you didn't want to fly anyway and not board the plane...

The odds of either of these occurring, and of you being able to benefit from them, is low - but it's not zero.  You will need to balance that with the additional inconvenience you will cause the airline staff and potentially other passengers on the flight by checking in.

As for your comment about the airline not being paid until you check in, this is absolutely not true. The airline gets their money regardless of whether you check in or not - in fact most of the time (even when booking via a travel agency) it's the airline themselves that actually charges your credit card, so they have the money from the moment the trip is ticketed.

Comment: If you have luggage, turning around and leaving isn't just "rather odd", it's extra pain for everyone while they remove your luggage too.

Comment: @Mehrdad That's a generic issue of throw-away ticketing, and not relevant for this specific question/answer. (And for US domestic flights, they don't remove your luggage anyway)

Comment: It feels fraudulent to claim compensation for a delay to a flight when you weren't even at the airport to catch it. Are you even entitled to compensation in that case? If not, then claiming the compensation is literally fraudulent. Even if you are entitled to compensation, that sounds like exactly the sort of situation in which the airline would be very liable to enforce its terms and conditions about throwaway ticketing, if it found out what you did.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: you're indeed entitled to claim compensation for cancellation (in EU) without being present at the airport if a flight was canceled and there's less than 14 days before departure. For involuntary boarding denial and delay compensation you have to be present at gate.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'd like to clarify the checkin part (i.e. when the airline gets paid) as it contradicts an existing upvoted answer and it is important.

Comment: @GeorgeY. Sounds like a great topic for a new question then!

Comment: @DavidRicherby You sign a contract with the airline stipulating that they reserve a seat for you on route X flying from A to B. If, for any reason, the airline announces your reservation is void, they have to pay out a compensation. Whether or not you intended to take that specific flight is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @JonathanReez And, as part of that contract, you also agreed to show up for the flight, and not engage in practices that the airline doesn't like, such as throwaway ticketing. Since the passenger intends to breach the contract by skipping the flight, it's not at all clear that the same contract affords them any rights, depending on when the cancellation and when the breach are deemed to have happened.

Comment: @DavidRicherby yeah but the flight cancellation happens *before* the scheduled time (usually) and therefore it's irrelevant if you would have actually taken the flight if it proceeded as planned. So unless the airline has *very* strong proof you weren't going to fly anyway, they're liable for compensation.

Comment: At KLM now you can get some money on an throwaway return even without going to airport if it is overbooked - the system automatically asks you during check-in if you're willing to give up your seat for a compensation. And allows you to choose the number. Of course you're getting airline credit, not real money - but better than nothing, and airlines tend to be quite generous with those.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no advantages to the traveler.

If you fully intend to skip that segment, please, do not check in.

All you will be doing is creating more work for the Gate Staff, especially if the flight is full or near full.

Also, if you fully intend to miss the flight, don't pre-select a seat or, pick a really bad one, middle last row.

**You will not accrue miles or points and the airline does not receive the revenue when you check in.**

The value of the ticket is still yours for perhaps up to 1 year.

Comment: John, thanks for your answer, but I'm asking about practical advantages/disadvantages **for a traveler**. Also if the agent part is correct, and the airline only gets paid when I check in, it looks like an advantage for the airline. And middle-last is my favorite seat on a flight which I know won't be full, as it practically guarantees you an empty row.

Comment: While not really substantial, I think this answer is just good enough not to rate deletion as low quality. Downvoting is the better option if you disagree, which I do not do.

Comment: The answer if perfectly valid for the circumstances because the traveler must be aware of the *consequences* of this decision.  It is not worthy of a downvote but for the regular people who work for the airlines, I'll take it, I don' care.

Comment: The value of the ticket is NOT yours for 1 years. Almost all tickets will have zero value after the flight departs unless you cancel the flight, and that is generally not possible on throw-away tickets as it will cause a reprice which defeats the entire purpose

Comment: @Willeke I agree. This is a comment, not an answer. Though comment is perhaps a bit generous, perhaps "rant" is more appropriate

Comment: This is all funny.  I offer valid, but different, perspective on the situation described.  Seems 6 people have found it useful so I thank them for their appreciation.  BTW, you do retain the value  the ticket.  The effective value might end up being 0 due to pricing and fees but there's a pile of rules so any more specific answer is not possible.

Comment: @Johns-305: You state that **"You will not accrue miles or points"** - but this contradicts my personal experience. I'd speculate that you *will* get miles if you bought a ticket from airline A, and your return flight is on airline B. Also I've got miles twice on the flights I didn't take **even on the same airline** (both overbooked, I volunteered  for the next day flights - got miles even before taking those next flights). This strongly suggests miles accrual is tied up to check-in and not to boarding, at least in some cases.

Comment: @Johns-305: also I don't think "The value of the ticket is still yours for perhaps up to 1 year" is correct at all if you already flew the first leg. You only have the ability to change the leg for a hefty fee, and if you don't do this, there is no value left on the ticket anymore after the return leg departs.

Comment: @GeorgeY.You either benefitted from a glitch or the miles were based on fare paid.  For a non-refundable fare, it's conceivable that they will award even if you don't fly since you're not getting the money back.  Different programs, different rules.  However, you will not get flown based status miles if you don't actually fly.  If you don't board, you will be removed from the manifest regardless of check in status.

Comment: @GeorgeY. The thing is, the Itinerary, the Ticket(s) and the value are all different things.  If you miss a flight, the Itinerary will be cancelled, the ticket probably voided, but the value remains.  Yes, using that value is often not possible due to how trips are priced and various fees, but the value does remain.  That's why I say effective value, which is the result after you try to use it.

Comment: @Johns-305: the question I asked is **from the traveler's perspective**. It is not relevant for us how those things are managed in airline computers or accounting sheets. If we cannot use this value, it is zero for us. Please note this is travel.stackexchange.com - not runningairline.stackexchange.com